# One hover_tool cutting across multiple lines?

Tags: bokeh

How would you go about reproducing this d3 code in Bokeh?

http://bl.ocks.org/wdickerson/64535aff478e8a9fd9d9facccfef8929

Comment: Are you asking about just displaying the data from multiple lines in one hover tool? If you are referring to the vertical line, then this might be useful: https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/#!topic/bokeh/-tXIkFHmY8I

Comment: Thanks, that helped!